# Ajax response to load dynamically the returning javascript in a specific div

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a php file that returns a div and a javascript. 
I want to change a specific div (actually its contents) so the code for Ajax is the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changemainpage(id) {


  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   { //code for IE7+. Ffirefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }  
   else { //code for IE6,IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }


   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    { 
        HandleResponse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","./newgraph.php?id=unit"+id,true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);

}

function HandleResponse (response) {

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=response;
    document.getElementById('content').src=document.getElementById('content').src;
}


function ChangeMainContent(id, graph){
    $('#content').load('newgraph/index.php?id=' + id,'&graph='+graph);
}

</script>
```

Now the problem lies that when the content is changed it is not parsed as a javascript. Here is php code in newgraph.php

```
<?php 
echo "<!--dygraphs are not happy when placed inside a <center> tag. If you want to center a Dygraph, put it inside a table a table with align=center set. For more options go to dygraphs.com/options-->\n
<div id=\"graphid\" onLoad='refresh()' style=\"width:320px; height:290px;\"></div>\n";

?>
<?php 
//$table="unit1";
$table=$_GET['id'];
$ylabel="EnergyReckVARh"; //Available are Error BIT(1), UTCOffsetMin SMALLINT, LocalDatetime DATETIME, EnergyDeliveredkWh INT, EnergyReceivedkWh INT, EnergyDelkVARh INT, EnergyReckVARh INT, ApparentPowerTotalkVA SMALLINT, RealPowerTotalkW SMALLINT, ReactivePowerTotalkVAR SMALLINT
$outfile='outfile.csv';

echo $table;
//delete file in case it exists
//unlink($outfile);

//show database table
    include './database/config.php';
    include './database/opendb.php';

    $csv_output.='LocalDatetime,';
    $csv_output.=$ylabel;
    $csv_output.="\n";

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT LocalDatetime,".$ylabel." FROM ".$table." ORDER BY LocalDatetime");
    $dbcols = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $dbrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        for ($i=0;$i<$dbcols;$i++){
            $csv_output.=$row[$i].",";
        }
        $csv_output=substr_replace($csv_output,"",-1);  //remove that last ","
        $csv_output.="\n";
    };

    $handle=fopen($outfile, 'w') or die ("Can;t open file");
    fwrite($handle, $csv_output);
    fclose($handle);

    //close database
    include './database/closedb.php';

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var datamatrix=[];\n";


    //\"2008-05-07 18:00:00,75\\n\" +
    //\"2008-05-07 18:05:00,90\\n\" +
    //\"2008-05-07 18:06:00,80\\n\",
echo    "var ylabel='".$ylabel."';
    var tablet='".$table."';";


 echo "  
   var opts =     {
    title: ylabel+' for '+tablet,   
    ylabel: ylabel,     
    //showRangeSelector: true,
    legend: 'always',
    //rollPeriod: 50,
    showRoller: true,
    rangeSelectorPlotFillColor: '#A7B1C4',
    rangeSelectorPlotStrokeColor: 'red',
    fillGraph: true,
    //rangeSelectorHeight: '30'

    };

    alert(\"New Javascript is running\");
    g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById(\"graphid\"),
    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    //\"Date,$ylabel\\n\" +\".\"\n
    \"$outfile\",
    //\"outfile.csv\",
    opts
    );
";

echo "</script>";

echo "dbrows are $dbrows";

?>
```

The php file returns the code but it is not parsed as a javascript, i.e. the alert does not pop up a new window! If I run it from the start everything works great. I though the

```
    document.getElementById('content').src=document.getElementById('content').src;
```

would do the trick but this is not the case. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are creating your own Xml Request as you are already using jQuery.

Just throw your complete JS code away and do this:

```
function changemainpage(id) {
    $('#content').load('./newgraph.php?id=unit'+id);
}
```

And jQuery will execute the JS code included in the incoming page as well.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. All I see is an empty white page replacing the previous one. Plus jQuery was just a leftover. I don't use it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you are right. I had the min version of jQuery that didn't do it. Now I am using google's api jquery and everything works as you said.... I feel dumb. I suppose it will work offline if I download it, right?

Comment: Yes, if you download it, it will work offline as well. But that has nothing to do with the "min" version, that should work exactly like the other. The min version is just "min"ified, so all unneeded whitespaces, comments etc are remove to get the lowest possible file size.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that instead. The code seems better to handle. From http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js it doesn;t work while from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js it works... What can I say...

Comment: I was downloading the ui version... *facepalm*